# Difference between plugin and widget in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am a beginner WordPress developer. Please help me with this query.

What is the Difference between plugin and widget in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Diffrence: The first and most obvious difference is that plugins are rarely visible to the public, as they work mostly in the back-end, but they always improve your site’s interface. On the other hand, a widget is a representation of a plugin that is placed somewhere on the site, visible to everyone, and it can be easily managed from your dashboard without having to install anything. For your refrence, please find below Poplar plgin & widget list.

Popular Plugin

- WooCommerce
- Contact Form 7
- Divi

Popular Widget:

- WP Call Button
- Google Maps Widget
- Social Count Plus

PLUGIN

-A plugin is a collection of files that either change the way WordPress functions or adds/removes functionality.

-Plugin provides plug and play(install and use)functionality so you can use ready code on your site

-Plugins can be added anywhere.

WIDGET

-Widgets are drag-and-drop content areas that present data or an user interface to the user.

-You can’t install widgets like you can plugin but some plugins have inbuilt widget option.

-Widgets mostly used in sidebars, footer and header(widgetized area).

Answer (score 0):

If it keeps your page running and functioning properly in the background, it’s a plugin. If a user can see it and interact with it on the page, it’s a widget.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).